# Display percentage of progress every time a command is executed in a bash script

Tags: bash, unix, terminal, scripting

I have a bash script that executes four commands

```
zmprov -ga something
zmprov -ga something else
zmprov -ga something else something else 
zmprov -ga something else something else something else
```

How could I make it so every time a command is executed it shows an echo showing percentage of completion?
I could do echo "20% complete" and so forth just now because there are only 4 commands but this list may grow to a variable number of commands down the road.

Also, how can I make it so it doesn't display on screen the actual commands being executed and only shows the echo containing the completion percentage?

Answer (score 0):

You can preregister the commands to an array before executing them; using `printf %q` before storing them to allow them to be safely evaluated later using the `eval` command. You can calculate the percentage based on the number of registered tasks.

Something like this:

```
cmds=()
printf -v "cmds[${#cmds[@]}]" '%q ' cmd1 "arg with space"
...
for i in "${!cmds[@]}"; do
    perc=... # TODO: Calculate percentage using i and ${#cmds[@]}
    echo -e "[${perc}%] ${cmds[i]}"
    eval "${cmds[i]}"
done
```

Comment: Thank you! I have never used an array in bash, what would the proper syntax be in this case?
`code
cmds=(
cmd1 here
cmd2 here
cmd3 here
)
`
like this?
`
Thank you again!

Comment: Bash only supports linear arrays so each command would have to be "encoded" while they are being stored. See the `printf` command above. Please read the [Arrays](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Arrays.html) section of the Bash manual and also look at "Word Splitting" and "Filename Expansion" section. The process of storing and executing stored commands is delicate especially in this case where we have to use `eval` so you have to learn how to use quotes properly.

Comment: would it work if every command line is added to a variable and I include all the variables within the array?

Comment: You can add declaration commands of variables to the `cmds` array much like simple commands.

Comment: ok so just so I understand, i could have a variable called cmd1=a very long command goes here ............................... cmd2= and so forth and include in the array $cmd1 $cmd2? etc?

Comment: No I didn't mean `cmd1` above as a variable and neither would you have store a command on a variable first before storing it as an element in the `cmds` array. You store the command right away as a quoted command and this can be done using printf.  Please run `help printf` to know how `printf` works. It only produces a single string and with `-v` it assigns it to a variable, or an element of an array which in this case is what we do. Call the printf command above multiple times to register more commands. Also run `help eval` to make sure you know the end goal.

Comment: Try running those commands step by step. You can see how  variables store their current values using `declare -p`. You can also make your script print commands as it goes by running with the `-x` option. E.g. `bash -x script.bash`.